# Match all files with extension in document root only

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match only HTML files that are within the document root and not match any within subdirectories.

I have tried a number of online regex testers, but I am not very adept at regex so I am fumbling around with them more than anything. Here is the closest match I have been able to create.

```
(?!(\/))([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.html
```

This unfortunately matches anything with the .html extension which I do not want.

For the following paths:

```
/dir1/file.html
/dir2/file.html
/file.html
/file-name---is--something.html
```

It should only match /file.html and /file-name---is--something.html but matches them all.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\/[^\/]*\.html$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMHOES/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - a `/` char (no need to escape it if not used as a regex delimiter char - depends on the environment)
- `[^\/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
- `\.html` - `.html` string
- `$` - string end.

Comment: Thanks, that got me in the right direction! I used ^(\/[^\/].*)\.html$ to capture the filename.

Comment: I did, but it gave me some message about not having enough credibility on my account because it isn't very active? Anyway, I did it again and it looks like it took this time.